# Length in bytes of a String

Tags: rascal

Is there a function in the Rascal Lib where I get the length in bytes of a String?

A bit similar as the getFileLength() function in IO.

I need it for setting an offset in a Location value.

Comment: Bytes don't exist in Rascal. You can think or even have to think in terms of characters. Unicode that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/String/size/size.html

The size function does exactly what you need:

.   size("was") == 3

Comment: Already tried that, maybe it is an encoding issue..     
I want to count the offset so far, while reading a java source file line by line. But when i use size() it always comes up short (offset becomes to small).                     
I found that this happend when \t characters occurred at the begin of the string, so I tried to adjust for that (by adding +1 to the offset). Still not correct however...         
getFileLength() in IO returns the same length for a location as M3 does, and it's description talks about bytes so that why..

Comment: The lines are interesting because the character encoding for newlines may be different on different operating systems. For every line on Unix you would have to add 1 and on Windows probably 2

Comment: I don't know about how get file length and the bytes thing. Will check later

Comment: I see it, readFileLines() removes \r\n characters for each line. Adding 2 to the size of the line results in the correct offset. Thanks.